# Отправка данных из dropdown меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Мне нужно сверстать красивый dropdown который находится в форме, но стандартный select тяжело поддается стилизации, намного удобно через `ul li` сделать. Как потом мне отправлять данные на сервер из dropdown  построенном на `ul li`?

Comment: А почему Вам не подходят готовые решения типа https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1 data атрибутами

```js
var selected;

$('.dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function () {
   selected = {
     id:$(this).data('id'),
     text: $(this).text()
   }
   console.log(selected);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#" data-id="one">Один</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="two">Два</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="three">Три</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Вариант 2 свойствами dom элемента.

```js
selectObj = [
 {id:'one', text: 'Один'},
 {id:'two', text: 'Два'},
 {id:'three', text: 'Три'},
]



$(document).ready(defaultInit);

function defaultInit() {

   for(var i = 0; i < selectObj.length; i++){
     $block = getBlock();
     $block.get(0).val = selectObj[i].id;
     $block.find('a').text(selectObj[i].text);
     $('.dropdown-menu').append($block)
  }
  
   $('body').on('click','.dropdown-menu li', function () {
       selected = {
         id:$(this).get(0).val,
         text: $(this).text()
       }
       console.log(selected);
    })
  
}
function getBlock() {
  return $('<li/>').append($('<a/>'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Тут ключевое отличие в том что задаётся не data атрибут, а свойство элемента `$block.get(0).val = selectObj[i].id;` и соответственно выборка будет `$(this).get(0).val`

Ну а имея selected запрос отправляется обычным аяксом

Answer (score 1):

Если сабмит без js, то оборачивайте список в форму, в li заворачивайте input, сабмитьте.

Answer (score 0):

В элементы `li` можно добавить атрибут `data-val` в котором будет содержаться значение для элемента. При выборе элемента выпадающего списка добавлять к выбранному `li` атрибут, допустим `selected`.

После чего отправлять данные на сервер можно при помощи **javascript**, в качестве **ajax** запроса с данными формы.

Поскольку вы используете **Bootstrap** получить выбранный элемент из выпадающего списка можно легко при помощи jQuery, к примеру: `$('ul > li[selected]').attr('data-val');`

Соответственно при помощи jQuery можете отправлять **ajax** запрос используя функцию [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) или [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Солидарен с ответами выше, но еще бы хотел уточнить.

```
    $( "#Form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Функция которая отменяет submit и страница не перезагружается
        // Тут с помощью jquery создаете select но делаете его multiple, и все данные которые вы выбирите - append делаете в селект.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать обычный селект, который будет копией кастомного, передавать выбранное значение туда, отправлять на сервер данные как обычно.

```js
$(function(){
  var i;
  
  $('ul li').click(function() {
    i = $(this).index();
    
    $('select option').prop('selected', false).eq(i).prop('selected', true)
  });
});
```

```css
li { cursor: default; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>option 1
  <li>option 2
  <li>option 3
</ul>

<select>
  <option>option 1
  <option>option 2
  <option>option 3
</select>
```